# Change panel collapse to false based on action extjs4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a panel that i'm using to attach files. And gave it collapsed:true. Now what i'm trying to do is that after the attach, i need to change collapsed to false.. Any idea on what to use to do so?

```
var docsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                id : 'docs_panel',
                layout:'anchor',
                region : 'east',
                width: 225,
                collapsed:true,
                collapsible:true,
                autoScroll: true,
                singleSelect : true,
                cls : 'thumbs',
                items : new Ext.view.View({
                    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('docs_store'),
                    tpl : tpl,
                    autoWidth : true,
                })
    });
```

Comment: Call the `expand` method.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli i tried docsPanel.expand(); but didn't work

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15fg